# How to simulate the submission of web form entries in an ios app

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to simulate the entry of a string in a textbox on a web form, submit that form, and then receive the result back from the server.  The idea is to allow the user to input the relevant form field in a native iOS control, and then grab the data they're after for them (it requires a few intermediate steps).

The site in question is this: https://www.sinet.uq.edu.au/psp/ps/EMPLOYEE/HRMS/c/UQMY_GUEST.UQMY_GUEST_TTBLE.GBL

I want to provide values for the 'select semester' dropdown (id="UQ_DRV_TT_GUEST_STRM"), and for the 'course code' textbox (id="UQ_DRV_CRSE_SRC_UQ_SUBJECT_SRCH").

To submit, I want to simulate hitting the 'Search' button at the bottom of the page (id="UQ_DRV_TT_GUEST_UQ_SEARCH_PB", onclick="hAction_win0(document.win0,'UQ_DRV_TT_GUEST_UQ_SEARCH_PB', 0, 0, 'Search', false, true);").

I've looked into using an ASIFormDataRequest object from the ASIHTTPRequest library to send through POST values, but either I'm getting the key/value pairs wrong or I'm approaching this in the wrong way.

If someone could point me in the right direction that'd be great.  In particular, should I be somehow running the hAction_win0(...) call, and if so, how would I set the appropriate values?  If this isn't necessary, what should the POST values be?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a JavaScript to set the values, use following code to evaluate it in browser:

```
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:JSstring];
```

Comment: I was intentionally attempting to avoid using a WebView, but I since gave up and did it using a hidden one anyway.  I did it independantly, but since we came to the same conclusion I might as well accept this :P

Answer (score 0):

Create a NSString with the fields separated by a "&". For example, say I have two fields: name and email. Then it should be:

> @"name='John Balls'&email='john@mac.com'";

Create a NSData object from that string by using -dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding and send it as the HTTP body.

Comment: This is a really stupid question, but what specifies a field in HTML?  Is it the id property?

The more relevant thing: when I do this:
request.HTTPBody = [@"UQ_DRV_CRSE_SRC_UQ_SUBJECT_SRCH='METR3200'" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

The connection doesn't ever receive a response.

I can do HTTP Post using an ASIFormDataRequest if that's all that's needed, but it wasn't seeming to do anything when I tried.